# how to send subject & content variable to mail with queue

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

i am trying to send email after posting blog when i post mail sent but when i try to add variable to subject its show me error undefined $blog
here is my controller

```
$blog = new Blog;
    $blog->title = $request->title;
    $blog->content = $request->content;
    $blog->slug = str_slug($blog->title, '-');
    $blog->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $blog->published_at = $request->published_at;
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = Input::file('image');
        //getting timestamp
        $timestamp = str_replace([' ', ':'], '-', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/blog/', $name);
        $blog->image = $name;
        $thumb = Image::make(public_path().'/images/blog/' . $name)->resize(640,420)->save(public_path().'/images/blog/thumb/' . $name, 90);
    }
    $blog->save();
$subscribers = Subscriber::get();
    foreach ($subscribers as $subscribe) {
        $mail = Mail::to($subscribe->email)->send(new BlogPost($blog));
    }


    return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Post Success');
```

here is my email class BlogPost.php on app/mail/

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class BlogPost extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($blog)
    {
        $this->blog = $blog;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.new_blog')
                    ->subject('this is test email subject')
                    ->with([
                        'title'     =>  'This is Testing Email',
                        'content'     =>  'this is something else',
                    ]);
    }
}
```

i am missing something i don't know or i don't know how to send variable to subject or title or content

Comment: Where is the `$blog` variable actually used? I don't see it in the `BlogPost` code, apart from the constructor.

Comment: i solve this thank you i forgot to add protected $blog;